# unity PostLateUpdate.UpdateAudio high cpu usage

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was running the profiler on my game and i noticed that every time i jumped, which called an AudioSource.Play() for a jump sound, it would spike the CPU usage through PostLateUpdate.UpdateAudio. I can't find much about it when i research it.

Does anyone know whats going on or what i can look to do to mitigate this? When i don't play any jump sound there is no problem, but i have to have a jump sound. I found that when i switch the sound files for jump, some of them have the same effect and some of them don't. Any ideas? They're all .wav files and im not sure what the difference is here. thanks

[image: Pic]

Answer (score 1):

Another quick mystery here. I found out that my audio file settings were different in unity itself.

The Load Type for the jump was **Streaming** while the others were **Decompress on Load**. Once i changed that, the spike went away. I'm not sure what the difference is but i'm sure to read into it.